# require lib in RSpec with Ruby 1.9.2 brings "no such file to load"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, require, ruby-1.9

I am trying to upgrade one of my Rails projects to `Ruby 1.9.2`. All went pretty well, but one RSpec test broke. In this test I `require` a Ruby `lib`:

```ruby
# file spec/models/my_lib_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
require 'lib/services/my_lib'

describe "MyLib" do

  it "should do something" do
...
```

The lib looks like this:

```ruby
# file lib/services/my_lib.rb
class MyLib

  def self.do_something
  ...
```

In Ruby 1.8.7 (REE) the test worked well:

```
$ ruby -v   
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i686-darwin11.1.0], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby
Enterprise Edition 2011.03
$ rspec ./spec/models/my_lib_spec.rb
..

Finished in 1.4 seconds
2 examples, 0 failures
```

In Ruby 1.9.2 I get an Error `no such file to load`:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin11.1.0]
$ rspec ./spec/models/my_lib_spec.rb
/Users/tmangner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@madgoal/gems/activesupport-
3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': no such file
to load -- lib/services/my_lib (LoadError)
```

I have no clue, what keeps Ruby 1.9 from finding the lib.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The load path in ruby 1.9 doesn't work exactly like it did in 1.8.

You need to add the project's root directory to your load path.

You can do this by either running rspec like this:

```
rspec -I . ./spec/models/tipp_remember_spec.rb
```

...or by manually adding stuff to the load path in your `spec_helper.rb` (put this at the top of your `spec_helper.rb`

```
$:<< File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..')
```

I think rspec by default adds your local `lib` directory to the load path as well, so you might be able to rewrite the require line as follows instead:

```
require 'services/my_lib'
```

Comment: The last part of your answer was the key! "require 'service/my_lib'" works in Ruby1.9 _and_ Ruby1.8. Obviously RSpec does include 'lib' into the $LOAD_PATH.

Comment: great! rspec `- I .` is the key for me when upgrading ruby from 1.8 to 1.9. thanks a lot @Frost!

Comment: If you don't want to specify `-I .` each time you run `rspec` you can add it to your .rspec file and it will be added by default.

Answer (score 6):

In RSpec 2.x, the `lib` directory is automatically added to the load path (see [RSpec-Core#get_started](http://rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/file/README.md#get_started)).

So you can just use `require 'services/my_lib'` in your spec file.

Comment: I can not see  `the lib directory is automatically added to the load path` anywhere , but it is true

Comment: @why I fixed the broken link. Looks like it's not explicitly stated in there, but the example does show it implicitly used. I'll try to get that fixed.

Comment: For RSpec 3.5 (latest) the link is [here](http://rspec.info/documentation/3.5/rspec-core/index.html#Get_Started).

Answer (score 4):

If your spec is located `spec/models/my_lib_spec.rb` and you want to test `lib/services/my_lib.rb`, then just tell the spec how to get to the lib file

```
require 'spec_helper'
require_relative '../../lib/services/my_lib'

describe "MyLib" do

  it "should do something" do
```

Final note: since you're including spec_helper, you typically don't have to give all paths to dependencies, since Rails should load all of these for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining the path manually

`$LOAD_PATH << './lib/services/'`

and then add the library like this

```rb
require 'my_lib.rb'
```