# How to include lib directory in rspec tests

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, rspec-rails

I am having a problem in testing my gem which includes a `lib` directory, on JRuby 1.7.4.

I want to test a file located at `lib/vger/resources/account_manager.rb`

My spec file is in `spec/vger/resources/account_manager_spec.rb`

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Vger::Resources::AccountManager do     
    .
    .
    end 
end
```

I am trying to include the file which I want to test in `spec_helper.rb`

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'vger/resources/account_manager'
require 'vger'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # some (optional) config here
end
```

While running the test by the command `rspec spec/vger/resources/account_manager_spec.rb` I am getting this error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Vger::Resources
    const_missing at org/jruby/RubyModule.java:2631
```

I seems that the file which I want to test is not getting loaded. Please tell me where I am going wrong and where should I make corrections.

Comment: Try to use `require_relative` and path to resources in lib directory from directory where `spec_helper.rb` is. Something like `require_relative "../lib/vger"` instead of `require "vger"` ant etc.

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev It doesn't seem to work. I tried require_relative '../lib/vger/' also require_relative '../lib/vger/resources/' and remove requre 'Vger' and require "vger/resources/account_manager"

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376718/require-lib-in-rspec-with-ruby-1-9-2-brings-no-such-file-to-load

Answer (score 21):

Manually update your LOAD PATH in spec_helper.rb before calling `require` should do the trick. Try making this the first line of your spec_helper.rb:

```
$: << '../lib'
```

or

```
$LOAD_PATH << '../lib'
```

(`$:` is an alias for `$LOAD_PATH`)

Comment: I tried it. /home/...../work/vger/lib seem to be getting loaded but still getting the same error

Comment: Consider not using `$:` It is very cryptic and since `$LOAD_PATH` is oh so unoffensive to type, so you might as well just use it instead.  But +1 for the inclusion.

Answer (score 13):

You can add the following line to your `.rspec` file in app’s root:

`-I lib`

It’s also possible to include files:

`-r lib/api.rb`

These options are described as follows:

> -I PATH
>
> Specify PATH to add to $LOAD_PATH (may be used more than once).
>
> -r, --require PATH
>
> Require a file.

Answer (score 7):

I use the following for my specs...depending on which level your lib is....

`require_relative '../../lib/module'`

Comment: You may wish to improve your answer with a few more details.  One of the comments has a bit more info that you could include.

Answer (score 1):

RSpec loads rails environment, as I remember, so you just need to add to autoload directories in your application.rb file

Find this line

```
# config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)
```

uncomment it fix it to be like this:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

it should work

Comment: This is not a rails project. This is a gem which I am using in a rails application. SO, I guess it won't work

Comment: I assume this will recursively autoload the path? So for example, any rake tasks under `/lib/tasks` will also be loaded?